# Optimise Running Multiplication Calculation in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a large database table with about 2400 records and when I run the function below:

```
SELECT (SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG((cast(t1.NAT as float) + ISNULL(cast(t1.Dist as float),0))/cast(t1.NAT as float)))) FROM Test t1 where t1.CODE = t2.CODE AND t1.DATE <= t2.DATE) as Distro FROM Test t2
```

The code above causes performance issues as it goes through every row. Is there a way to optimise it? Are there any mistakes I am making?

The table I use this function on doesn't have its data sorted by DATE and I cannot sort it.

Comment: You care calling multiple functions on multiple columns for your equation so naturally this is a RBAR procedure. 2400 records isn't a lot of records, though. Do you have an index on the `[Date]` field? It would help on the `JOIN`. I assume not by your comment of *unsorted* data. You could change the column types of `NAT` and `Dist` to `DECIMAL` at the table level and avoid these casts. Or, you may not need them period. Just multiply them by 1.0 so that you don't get integer division.

Comment: @scsimon Removing the casts does not change much. But I did however change the fields to decimals but the performance is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below JOIN version of your query

```
SELECT 
    Distro=EXP(SUM(LOG( 1 +  ISNULL(cast(t1.Dist as float)/cast(t1.NAT as float),0))))
FROM 
Test t1 
    JOIN 
 Test t2
        On t1.CODE = t2.CODE AND t1.DATE <= t2.DATE
```

Also if your problems are functions you can also get same results using

```
DECLARE @result float=1
 SELECT 
        @result=@result*( 1 +  ISNULL(cast(t1.Dist as float)/cast(t1.NAT as float),0))
    FROM 
    Test t1 
        JOIN 
     Test t2
            On t1.CODE = t2.CODE AND t1.DATE <= t2.DATE

SELECT Distro=@result
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to optimise it? Are there any mistakes I am making?

Yes.

This is a triangular join.

You say that the table has 2,400 rows. Assuming that there is only one `CODE` for simplicity then even if there is an index on `CODE, DATE` the subquery would need to process on average half the table (the outer row with the lowest date would only cause one row to be summed but by the time the highest date is encountered it needs to sum the whole `2,400` rows.

So in total the number of rows being summed would be `2,881,200` (`2400 * 2401 / 2`).

Your situation likely isn't as bad as that - dependent on how many `CODE` you do in fact have and how well distributed they are but still using window functions will be more efficient as they can do it with one pass through the data.

On the assumption that `CODE, DATE` is unique you can use

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Min(Abs(input)) 
                OVER ( 
                  PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY DATE) = 0 THEN 0 
         ELSE CASE 
                WHEN Sum(Sign(CASE 
                                WHEN input < 0 THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 
                              END)) 
                       OVER ( 
                         PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY DATE) % 2 = 1 THEN -1 
                ELSE 1 
              END * Exp(Sum(Log(Abs(NULLIF(input, 0)))) 
                          OVER ( 
                            PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY DATE)) 
       END 
FROM   Test t1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (( CAST(t1.NAT AS FLOAT) + ISNULL(CAST(t1.Dist AS FLOAT), 0) ) / CAST(t1.NAT AS FLOAT))) V(input)
```